# Call maven plugin goal inside a custom plugin with properties [Maven Plugin Development]

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-plugin-development

I am trying to call deploy goal inside custom plugin which identifies changed modules (mutlimodule maven project) and I need to run deploy goal only on those modules.

Setting skip properties from one goal and running deploy goal afterwards not working. I think its because setting system properties on first goal won't effect on second goal.

**execution:**
`mvn custom-plugin:identify-changes deploy`

custom-plugin internally sets differetn `skip.deploy.[module-name]` properties and deploy plugin configuration are configured accordingly in each module. This might work if I start deploy process from identify-changes goal. How can I do that or suggest any other approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best way is to create an extension....

Comment: you meant extending the `DeployMojo` for an example?